# jQuery Form Validation - https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator - EasyTabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, tabs

I use the jQuery plugin https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator together with responsive tabs and a problem arises during validation!

- Hidden fields seems to be validated. Is that a bug?
- Is it possible to disabled the validation of a form using this
  plugin?
- Is it possible to trigger the validation with an input of type
  "button"?

Thank you.

Comment: Ridiculous to put this question on hold. He's asking how to implement certain things using a certain jQuery plugin. Why shouldn't that be allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The plugin tried to validate forms that not visible, and so the validation doesn't pass.**

I'm guessing you mean inputs that is hidden. When you hide the input you should also remove, or rename, the attribute data-validation.

**Is it possible to remove validation from a form?**

Yes, simply remove or rename the attribute data-validation

```
function removeValidation($form) {
   $form.find('*[data-validation]').attr('data-validation', null);
}
```

**Is it possible for input type to be "button"?**

Yes, trigger validation when the button is clicked.

```
$.validate({
  form : '#my-form',
  onSuccess : function($form) {
     $form.get(0).submit();
  }
});

$('button.my-submit-button').on('click', function() {
  $('#my-form').trigger('submit');
});
```